# How can I implement Nancy.Authentication.Token in a web application?

Tags: security, authentication, nuget, token, nancy

I'd like to use the Authentication.Token method in a Nancy application, but there is not that package on NuGet yet.
I had a look on the [demo project](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/tree/master/src/Nancy.Demo.Authentication.Token) provided by Nancy staff, on Nancy Github, but it throws an exception on SafeGetNancyEngineInstance() in the Base Bootstrapper class. Also I'm not even able to split that project and make it works on his own.

So, what should I do to implement that package on my project? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was published the same day you ask

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Nancy.Authentication.Token/